# how to prove Exponential is strictly positive?

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that the exponential function is strictly positive ?

Comment: It's not strictly positive, with complex arguments. You might want to remove that tag.

Comment: Also, which definition do you want to start from?

Comment: power series only .

Comment: Can you show me when it will be zero in complex arguments ?

Comment: Are you aware of $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$?

Comment: yes i know that

Comment: but cosx and sinx will not give simultaneously a zero

Comment: No, but they will give negative numbers.

Comment: @Bob Example: $e^{i\pi}=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi=-1.$

Comment: By some methods of defining the value of an exponential function with a positive base at positive arguments, it's trivial that it's always positive.  But if one defines $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$, then it can well seem problematic.  Since there are several different characterizations of exponential functions, any of which may be taken to be the definition in some contexts, the posted question is not very well defined.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: in the third comment, OP mentions definition: _power series only_.

Comment: I've up-voted the question, so it must be that two people have down-voted it.

Comment: I was trying it using power series

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$e^x = \sum \frac {x^n} {n!} $$
Starting with this definition, it is obvious that $e^x > 0$ when $x \geq 0$. To show that $e^{-x} > 0$ it is enough to show that $e^{-x} \cdot e^x = 1$.

$$\sum_{n=0} \frac {(-x)^n} {n!} \cdot \sum_{m=0} \frac {x^m} {m!} = \sum_{m,n} \frac {(-x)^nx^m} {n!m!} = \sum _k \sum_{m+n = k} \frac{((-x)+x)^{n+m}}{(n+m)!} = 1$$

Here the second equality is due to $(a+b)^n = \sum_k \binom n k a^{n-k}b^k$ and the last one is due to $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: This shows that $\mathrm{e}^x\geq0$. How about exponential being _strictly positive_? Besides, OP's definition of exponential is by power series.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @Karolis Juodelė..... Can you just tell me what are the general ideas that should be followed to prove something non zero or strictly positive. and why in this case it is sufficient to prove $e^x*e^-x=1$

Comment: @Bob, if $e^x \cdot e^{-x} = 1$ and $e^x > 0$, then $e^{-x} = 1/e^x > 0$. The method for showing $f(x) > 0$ depends a lot more on the properties of $f$ then on the $> 0$ part.

Comment: @  Karolis Juodelė thanks

Answer (score 6):

The exponential function $\exp$ is the unique(!) solution of the differential equation $$\tag1 y'=y,\qquad y(0)=1.$$
However, if  $\exp(a)\ne0$, then $z\mapsto \frac1{\exp(a)}\exp(z+a)$ is also a solution. By uniqueness, we conclude $\exp(z)=\frac1{\exp(a)}\exp(a+z)$, provided $\exp(a)\ne 0$. 
Especially, $\exp(2z)=\exp(z)^2$ if $\exp(z)\ne 0$.

Let $z\in\mathbb C$ be arbitrary. Then from $2^{-n}z\to 0$ and $\exp(0)=1$ and continuity, we conclude that $\exp(2^{-n}z)\ne 0$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Then by repeated squaring $$\tag2\exp(z)=(\cdots(\exp(2^{-n}z\underbrace{)^2)^2)\cdots)^2}_n\ne 0.$$
We conclude that the complex exponential has no zeroes.
In the real case, $(2)$ shows that $\exp(z)>0$ because squaring a nonzero real number makes it positive.

*Remark:* If you start with a different definition of the exponentail, for example via the well-known power series, you can readily show that $(1)$ holds.