# prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I can't assume that this is the series representation of $e^x$.
I know how to do this for the case where $x\geq 0$. I'm struggling with the case $x < 0$. I have tried to split the series as

$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2l}}{(2l)!} - \frac{|x|^{2l+1}}{(2l+1)!}$

but it doesn't seem to work. Any hint?

Comment: I assume you're not allowed to just say right out that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$.

Comment: Prove $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\cdot\exp(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Arthur no I'm not.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855646/how-to-prove-exponential-is-strictly-positive

Comment: Daniel's suggestion shows that $\exp(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, and so $\exp(-x) = {1 \over \exp(x) }$. Since you already know that $\exp(x)$ is positive for $x \ge 0$, this gives you the answer.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, I get that. I'm trying to show what he suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining Daniel's suggestion and Robert's answer:

Let $\exp(x) = \sum_n { x^n \over n! }$. It is not hard to show that $\exp'=\exp$.

Let $\phi(x) = \exp(x) \exp(-x)$. Then $\phi(0) = 1$ and $\phi'(x) = 0$, hence $\phi(x) = 1$ for all $x$.

Since $\exp(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$, we see that
$\exp(-x) = {1 \over \exp(x)} > 0$.

Comment: thank you. This is much more elegant than what I was trying to come up with (involving binomial formula).

Comment: You are welcome, glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that this satisfies a differential equation...