# Proving $e^x\ge0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, alternative-proof

Given the series definition of $e^x$:

$$e^x=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

How does one show that $e^x\ge0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

One way is to show that

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

If $n>|x|$, $1+\frac{x}{n}>0$. By induction one can show $x^n>0$ for $x>0$, so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n>0^n=0$$

However, I was wondering if there was a more direct way to prove this, as proving the equivalence of the series and limit can be quite tedious.

For every $n\in\mathbb{Z}_0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$, $\frac{x^n}{n!}>0$, so $e^x\ge0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Also $e^0=1$ (as the other terms equal $0$).

The tricky part is in showing $e^x\ge0$ for $x<0$. My attempt was this:

Let $f(x)=e^x$ for notational simplicity. Suppose for the sake of contradiction, $f(x_0)<0$ where $x_0<0$. $f'(x)=f(x)$, so $f'(x_0)<0$. As $e^x$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta_0>0$ such that $|x-x_0|\le\delta_0\Rightarrow f(x)\le0$. Let $x_1=x_0+\delta_0$. So $\forall x\in[x_0, x_1]$, $f'(x)<0$. By MVT, $f(x_1)-f(x_0)=\delta_0f'(c)$ for some $c\in[x_0, x_1]$, and as shown earlier $f'(c)\le0$. As $\delta_0>0$,

$$f(x_1)-f(x_0)\le0\iff f(x_1)\le f(x_0)<0$$

We then construct $\delta_1>0$, and $x_2=x_1+\delta_1$ such that $f(x_2)\le f(x_1)<0$, and so on, ad infinitum.

The issue with this proof, however, is that I am unable to say anything about the size of $\delta_0, \delta_1, \delta_2, \cdots$. It is possible that

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\delta_n=L$$

for some finite $L$ (e.g. if $\delta_0=1, \delta_1=\frac{1}{2}, \delta_2=\frac{1}{4}$ e.t.c.). Through induction one can show $x_m=x_0+\sum^{m-1}_{i=0}\delta_i$, so

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}x_j=x_0+\sum^\infty_{n=0}\delta_n=x_0+L$$

And it is possible $x_0+L<0$, meaning there is no contradiction.

How can I fix this proof (or if it is unsalvageable, what would be a working proof?)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/855646/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1053132/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Out of curiosity, how did you find those questions? Though I suspected someone had asked about it, approach0 didn't provide a question so I asked.

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cexp(x)%20%3E%200%24) lists the dup target at the bottom of the first result page. A Google search for “exp positive site:math.stackexchange.com” gives also some results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** You can use the three following (and easy to prove, with the series definition) facts :

- $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous,
- $x \mapsto e^x$ does not vanish,
- $e^0=1$

Comment: What does it mean for a function to not vanish?

Comment: @Kyky It means that there does not exist a $x$ with $e^x=0$ (i.e. the function does not take the value $0$).

Comment: I think I need a bit of help showing $e^x$ doesn't vanish. I can show the other two though, and also how the three imply $e^x>0$ (via IVT).

Comment: @Kyky This one comes from the fact that $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$ (which can be proved by developping the Cauchy product). You deduce that $e^xe^{-x}=1$ for every $x$, and so $e^x \neq 0$.

Comment: @Kyky $e^x \cdot e^{-x} = 1$ ...

Comment: Ah, I see. I hadn't thought of applying $e^xe^{-x}$, thanks.

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times before.

Answer (score 3):

Once we've shown that $e^xe^{-x}=1$ (by the binomial theorem) the result follows more directly than people seem to have realized: It's clear from the power series that $e^x>0$ for $x\ge0$, and if $x<0$ then $$e^x=1/e^{-x}>0.$$

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times before.