# Is f(x,y)=exp(x-y) bounded below and if so, how to show it?

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

I know that $\lim_{x \to ∞} f(x,y) = 0$ and $\lim_{y \to ∞} f(x,y) = 0$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You say $f(x) = \exp(x-y)$, and use $\lim_{x, y\to\infty}f(x)$. Shouldn't that be $f(x, y)$? And if so, then those limits do not exist. The notion of $\lim{x, y\to a}$ for any $a$, be it a point in the plane or $\pm\infty$ is a lot more picky than you seem to think. Specifically, there is no requirement that $x$ and $y$ go towards $a$ in any kind of synchronized way.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to $f(x.y)=e^{x-y}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$\forall t\in \mathbb{R} \quad e^t>0$$

Refer to the related

- [how to prove Exponential is strictly positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/855646/505767)